# Image in rendering parameters to display background picture

Tags: jss

Here is what I'm trying to achieve :

- I have a component that has a parameter backgroundImage. This parameter was previously a field and I achieved what I wanted without any problem but in order to avoid saving an Item for my structure component I'd like to use a rendering parameter instead.
- I can get the params and see what I get for everything except my image. When I display what is in my backgroundImage parameter a string is returned containing this : `<image mediaid="{1551EAFF-E652-5213-BB93-5CB00B4EBC26}" />`
- Now what may I do with this string ? I use jss and sitecore 9.1.1

Comment: You can parse Id from string and build image ulr in format "/-/media/1551EAFFE6525213BB935CB00B4EBC26.ashx"

Comment: Nice solution @x3mxray thanks. I'm almost ready with your suggestion but I'm missing a thing : how to get the server URL if I'm working in jss connected mode ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this working using the following:

```
<img src={"/habitathomejss/-/media/"+props.params.Image.slice(props.params.Image.indexOf("{")+1,props.params.Image.indexOf("}")).replace(/-/g,"")+".ashx?h=50&w=94"}></img>
```

You need to make sure of the following:

1. The image is inside `/sitecore/media library/Project/TENANTNAME/SITENAME/data/media/img`
2. If you're using virtual paths that the virtual path is added (in my example it was habitathomejss)

Comment: This solution is somehow the solution proposed by @x3mxray . As I said this is working except if I'm working in jss start:connected mode. Then the URL is not correct as it is a local url instead of the one of the remote server. But as this is a solution I'll accept it as the good one.

Answer (score 1):

The `<image mediaid="{1551EAFF-E652-5213-BB93-5CB00B4EBC26}" />` is the raw database value for the image from Sitecore. To able convert it to an `img` tag you need to use the correct field from the JS library. For example here is the React component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image } from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-react';

const StyleguideFieldUsageImage = (props) => (
  <Image media={props.fields.backgroundImage} />
);
```

Here are the example apps for different frameworks:

- [Angular](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/dev/samples/angular/src/app/components/styleguide-field-usage-image/styleguide-field-usage-image.component.html)
- [React](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/dev/samples/react/src/components/Styleguide-FieldUsage-Image/index.js)
- [Vue](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/dev/samples/vue/src/components/Styleguide/Styleguide-FieldUsage-Image.vue)

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not an answer, the solution you give works for a field and not for params. I already stated that it works for a field in my question. The problem is that I'm getting a string, not an object from the params, so I can't pass a string to the Image tag: it just does nothing.